# play and pause using the same key in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-development

I'm new to action script 3 and I've made a simple pong game
now, I want it to pause when I press the space bar and also start when I press it again.

I've made a function the stops all the listeners and another one that plays them
the question is how do i make it tell the difference between the presses.

This is the function that I wrote:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pasueStart);

function pasueStart(e:KeyboardEvent):void{

  if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE) {
    removeListeners ();
  }
  if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE) {
    startCode ();
  }
}
```

What needs to be changed so it would work?

Answer (score 0):

A simple boolean expression will do what you want. Also your function name "pasueStart" should say "pauseStart" I'm assuming :)

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pauseStart);

var gamePaused:Boolean = false;

function pauseStart(e:KeyboardEvent):void{

  if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE && gamePaused == false) {
    removeListeners ();
    gamePaused = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE && gamePaused == true) {
    startCode ();
    gamePaused = false;
  }
```

}

Comment: I would rather not fiddle with listeners within this function, just toggle pause state and then check inside the listeners if the game is paused, if so, do only idle animation actions if any.

Comment: @tomkenar You're welcome, glad I could help. Please mark this question as answered